# MySQL - How to Write a UPDATE Query for Complex Dependant Calculations

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Here is a tabular representation of what I would like to achieve with an UPDATE statement.

```
+----+----+---+---+----+----------+----------+----------+
| ID | A  | B | C | D  |  CalcA   |  CalcB   |  CalcC   |
+----+----+---+---+----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |  6 | 5 | 2 | 10 | =See SQL | =See SQL | =See SQL |
|  2 |  8 | 5 | 2 | 10 | =See SQL | =See SQL | =See SQL |
|  3 | 10 | 5 | 2 | 10 | =See SQL | =See SQL | =See SQL |
+----+----+---+---+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

My Current UPDATE statement to achieve this is as follows...

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE
SET CalcA    = CASE A WHEN A - B THEN A + C WHEN C - D THEN A + B + C - D WHEN 3 THEN A * (B + C) WHEN 5 THEN A * D END
    , CalcB  = CalcA * 2 + (A + B + C + D) * 542 + (D * C) + A * 27
    , CalcC  = CalcB + A + B - C - D * 10
```

Now the calculation in its current form will not SET all the columns correctly in one execution because of their dependency's on the outcome of the previous calculation.

To correct this I could simply do all the calculations independently. i.e. ...

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE
    SET CalcA    = CASE A WHEN A - B THEN A + C WHEN C - D THEN A + B + C - D WHEN 3 THEN A * (B + C) WHEN 5 THEN A * D END
        , CalcB  = (CASE A WHEN A - B THEN A + C WHEN C - D THEN A + B + C - D WHEN 3 THEN A * (B + C) WHEN 5 THEN A * D END) * 2 + (A + B + C + D) * 542 + (D * C) + A * 27
        , CalcC  = ((CASE A WHEN A - B THEN A + C WHEN C - D THEN A + B + C - D WHEN 3 THEN A * (B + C) WHEN 5 THEN A * D END) * 2 + (A + B + C + D) * 542 + (D * C) + A * 27) + A + B - C - D * 10
```

However, as you can see this results in some very long calculations that are prone to error and difficult to check.

So my question is how do I get these calculations to work correctly in ONE update statement without having these extremely long SET calculations?

Comment: When wouldn't A-B? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @strawberry good point, ill try to provide questions with MCVE's next time! :)